# 12+ month business stay in Spain -- cost of life

Tags: eu-citizens, spain, cost-of-living

I'm offered a 12+ month long freelance work in Alicante, Spain with €3160 per month after tax. I know that this is a good salary, but I'd like to know how much of this I'll spend for everyday costs of living?

I'm EU citizen, 37 years old male. I'll be living in Spain alone.

I perfectly understand that these costs may vary much, based on how much do I spend on food, how will I be travelling (I don't plan to rent a car) and where I'll be living.

That's why I'm only asking for a very general information -- general average or medium range. I.e. will I spend €1000, €1500, €2000 or more?

If that may help -- I'll be staying alone and picking medium / cheap solutions where ever possible. I want to save as much as possible to support my abroad family and to visit them as often as possible (which requires a lot of air traveling and generates costs).

Is there any website or service (like [areavibes.com](http://www.areavibes.com/) for USA) which could allow me to estimate costs of living in Spain for single person? Or is there anyone here, who could shed any light of this topic? Even very general information will do, as I completely don't know where to start searching.

Answer (score 3):

I think this cannot really be answered, as it depends on your style of living.

There are millions of people in spain that live on less than 1000 €, so obviously it is possible. If you are willing to do with that level, only you can answer.

Comment: While I agree with your argument (that monthly costs of living very deeply depends on lifestyle) I don't agree with you, that my question is not answerable. Either I asked incorrectly or you missed my question's key point. I was looking for something similar to [this answer](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/9879/10823) (my own example for Poland) and many other similar questions and answers available here (found for UAE, Czech Republic, France and USA so far).